# Making return-type dependent on source of invocation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I wrote a c++-class that represents a mathematical matrix of arbitrary dimension NxM. Furthermore I also wrote a vector-class, deriving from it...

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
class matrix{ ... };

template<size_t N>
class vector : public matrix<N,1>{ ... };
```

...so that an N-vector can be treated as an Nx1-matrix, for example when it comes to multiplying with integral values or addition/subtraction of equally dimensioned matrices (or vectors in this regard).
The idea behind this is to avoid repeating code - which generally is a noble goal, I think. But here is the problem arising from it:

Here is your operator-overload for the addition, which only exists in the matrix-class:

```
matrix<N,M> operator+(const matrix<N,M>& right){
  //calculate some result and use it to construct a new instance
  return matrix<N,M>(result);
}
```

Making sure, the vector-class offers a copy-constructor for it's matrix-representation, it should be possible to say something like this:

```
vector<3> a(1,2,3);
vector<3> b(3,2,1);
a = a+b;
```

but you can't say this:

```
(a+b).some_vector_instance_method();
```

...because (a+b) isn't a vector.

**QUESTION: Is it possible to implement the matrix-operator+, so that it makes the return-type dependent on it's source of invocation? So, basically, if you invoke the + on a matrix, it should return a matrix; if invoked on a vector, it should return a vector.**

Now you can do this:

```
template<typename D>
D operator+(const D& right){
  //calculate result as usual, relying on 'right' to have what it takes
  return D(result);
}
```

... but it is unsafe as hell.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could write your `operator+` as a non-member function template (restricting its argument types by using a namespace + ADL or SFINAE).

Comment: @Dyp can you give a short example to illustrate your idea?

Comment: Here's a [small live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8e9e1797648f2a8).

Comment: @DyP Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this the same approach as mine, except for doing a static assertion, to check whether it's derived or not. For that, it doesn't need to be a non-instance-method, doesn't it? But anyway, it's a step in the right direction, I guess

Comment: My generic algorithm requires both arguments to be of the same type. `T` is deduced for the left and right side individually, and if it's not the same, then deduction will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple approach to implementation is to implement a member `operator+=()` for both `matrix<M, N>` and for `vector<M>` where the latter simply delegates to the former an the matrix operator has the actual operation. Using a bit of tagging the `operator+()` is then implemented as a non-member operator in terms of these operator. Here is a brief sketch:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace matrix_operators
{
    struct tag {};
    template <typename T>
    T operator+ (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return T(lhs) += rhs;
    }
}

template<size_t N, size_t M>
class matrix
    : matrix_operators::tag
{
public:
    matrix<N, M>& operator+= (matrix<N, M> const&) {
        std::cout << "matrix<" << N << ", " << M << "::operator+=()\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

template<size_t N>
class vector:
    public matrix<N,1>
{
public:
    vector<N>& operator+= (vector<N> const& other) {
        matrix<N, 1>::operator+= (other);
        return *this;
    }
    void some_other_method() {
        std::cout << "vector<" << N << ">::some_other_method()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<3> a, b;
    (a + b).some_other_method();
}
```

Comment: I don't get where the tag comes into play in your sketch

Comment: @armintamzarian: Defining an `operator+()` like the one in namespace `matrix_operators` in a form where it would match all types would be rather rude and, thus, it is hidden away into a namespace which is used to define `operator+()` and a `tag` type. To have the `operator+()` found in this namespace name it is necessary to cause look-up to looking in namespace `matrix_operations`. Since all namespaces which are associated with an object are searched it is sufficient to associate the namespace `matrix_operations` wit the `matrix` class. Namespaces of base classes are associated namespaces.

Comment: You know what? ... this might actually work. At least it makes sense to me. Dankeschön

Comment: I don't think the `vector::operator+=` is necessary. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e69385bf4d16323e)

Comment: @DyP me neither. I think it's just to differentiate between cases where you need the tagging, and cases where an instance-method is sufficient.

Comment: @armintamzarian: the `vector<N>::operator+=()` is necessary if the result of a `vector<N>` addition should be a `vector<N>` addition: without that operator there is no way to create a `vector<N>` from the `matrix<N, 1>` resulting from `matrix<N, 1>::operator+=()` used by `matrix_operations::operator+()`. You could avoid that problem by naming the temporary in `operator+()` but then it would be odd as `(vector<3>() += vector<3>()).some_other_method()` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Dietmar Sure, if your +-implementation from the tagged-space relies on a +=-operation (as in your example) then it's necessary. But it depends on the implementation. You don't necessarily have to do it that way.

Comment: @armintamzarian: yes. I could use `T tmp(a); tmp += b; return a;`. I know that. However, it wouldn't be consistent with `operator+=()` on `vector<N>`s: this operation would return a `matrix<N, 1>`.

Comment: @Dietmar That's true, doing it this way saves you from trouble with +=. I agree.

Comment: Interestingly, you can use the same technique as used for `operator+` to [provide a non-member `operator+=`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47da6e7527b72aac) for `vector` (that returns a `vector`) in namespace `matrix_operators`. It has to be greedy to be preferred over `matrix::operator+=` and can delegate the call via the explicit operator call syntax `lhs.operator+=(rhs)`.